# RouteTable Routes, Make my own proxy?

Tags: c#, wcf

I like to have control and know what happend, also i like to dont have any extension (.svc) inside my webservice. So i don't define any endpoints inside my `Web.config`. I use the `RouteTable` class to add `Routes`. Like these :

```
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(
            new ServiceRoute(@"Default",
                new CustomWebServiceHostFactory(),
                typeof(DefaultService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(
            new ServiceRoute(@"Customer",
                new CustomWebServiceHostFactory(),
                typeof(CustomerService)));
```

I try consume on the client side like these

```
_defaultService = new ChannelFactory<IDefaultContract>(
new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(@"http://myWeb.com/Default/")).CreateChannel();
```

I get the error: *"There was no endpoint listening at..."* 
With the browser i can call any operation (myWeb.com/Default/ReturnBool returns true)

Answer (score 0):

Have added a `BasicHttpBinding` ServiceEndpoint inside `CustomWebServiceHostFactory`, now i can consume the service as client if the contract is available.