# WCF Host service without extension with metadata to consume on clientside with known contract

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way to host a wcf service:

- without extension
- with relative endpoint addresses (the server address should be known automatically)
- without metadata (the contract is available for the client)
- basicHttp binding

If something is not achievable i will accept that. Already tried a approach but got
no metadata -> [Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728079/routetable-routes-make-my-own-proxy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're hosting a WCF (SOAP) service in IIS, you need a `service.svc` file (or at least an endpoint with the `.svc` extension using *file-less service activation* in .NET 4) so that IIS understands that this is a WCF SOAP endpoint and routes requests accordingly. In IIS, the virtual directory where your service lives basically determines your service endpoint's address, therefore you can use relative addresses (relative to the virtual directory) to define your service's endpoint address.

If you self-host your WCF service in a managed application (Windows NT Service, or just a plain .NET console app), then you don't need a `.svc` file - your managed app handles the requests - but at the same time, since there is no "hosting infrastructure" in place, you need to define a **fully qualified" endpoint address - you cannot just use a relative address (relative to what??)

So you can *either* have relative addresses (in IIS, but with a `.svc` file), or you can have *no extension* (with self-hosting, but then you must supply a fully qualified service endpoint address). You cannot have both at the same time.

Whether or not your service endpoint has and exposes metadata is just a question of adding (or *not* adding) the `ServiceMetaData` service behavior to your service definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question is still open. Can i consume the service without defining a metadata endpoint (the contract is available for the client).

Comment: @Abc: yes, of course. The metadata endpoint is only needed if you want to allow interactive discovery. If the client *knows* the contract and all the relevant info (endpoint address and binding), then the client can connect and use the service - no problem.